# Check on `window.ethereum` fails with Metamask active

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have a web frontend which checks for the `window.ethereum` object as follow

```
if(window.ethereum) {
    console.log("Metamask available")
    ...
} else {
    console.log("Metamask not available")
}
```

Metamask is active. When loading the page, I see from the Chrome dev tool console that the "Metamask not available" message is print. If in the same console I manually write the exact same code, it evaluate as correct. In fact, I can see that evaluating `window.ethereum` shows the Proxy object

[image: window.ethereum-correctly-shown]

This happens only on one device (Mac with Chrome), the same code works correctly on another one (Linux Chrome).

What could possible cause the same if condition to return false when the page load but true when manually evaluated from the dev tool console?

Note: the JS code above is included in an iFrame, if it makes any difference